# Confusion about ANTLR v4 rule priority

Tags: antlr4

The example from ANTLR website (https://www.antlr.org/) makes `*`/`/` be higher priority than `+`/`-`, but I'm confused with the meaning.

```
grammar Expr;       
prog:   (expr NEWLINE)* ;
expr:   expr ('*'|'/') expr
    |   expr ('+'|'-') expr
    |   INT
    |   '(' expr ')'
    ;
NEWLINE : [\r\n]+ ;
INT     : [0-9]+ ;
```

Because I think it's top-down parsing, if we input `100+2*34`, the `*`/`/` rule should be select first, makes it higher in the parsing tree, and so the result should be interpreted as `(100+2)*34`. But from the resulting parsing tree on the website, it's `100+(2*34)`.
Can someone help me to clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

The precedence for operators is indeed defined by the order of the alternatives in the `expr` rule. I assume by "higher in the parse tree" you mean the vertical position when printing the tree top-down, correct? However, when talking about the position of a tree node, you usually use the tree level (with the root being level 0). So, the deeper a node is in the tree, the higher is its position.

With that out of the way we can now look at your question: Of course the operators with lower precedence (here plus and minus) should appear at a lower level (closer to the root node), because evaluation of expressions begins at the leafs, that is, the deepest tree level.

Comment: Yes, what I mean "higher in the parse tree" is when printing like the graph show in the website, and so the root is the "highest" for what I mean.
So based on your explanation, I may conclude that the precedence by the alternative rules is for precedence of evaluation, and therefore for precedence when we construct parsing tree bottom-up. But as far as I know ANTLR is top-down parser generator, why the rule order is for bottom-up construction? This is what I can not understand.

Comment: Don't confuse tree creation and tree evaluation. Creation is top-down, yes, but evaluating an expression in an expression tree starts at the leafs, taking their values and applies the operation of their common parents, replacing the parent with the computed value (so the parent becomes a leaf). The evaluation starts over with the new leaf nodes.

Comment: Thank you. So could I understand that the priority of ANTLR grammar rules is the priority from bottom-up?

Comment: For expression evaluation, yes.